# Git not autocompleting with the switch command

Tags: windows, powershell, git, tab-completion

I'm trying to switch my behaivour to use `switch` and `restore` instead of `checkout`, but I'm running into a huge problem when trying to use `git switch` to switch branches. My company has a naming convention for our branches, that convention being that branches are named the same as the ticket is. So some of our branches have obscenely long names like `feature/ISSUE-123-really-long-title-of-the-issue-which-is-a-pain-to-copy-and-paste-like-this`. With `git checkout` I could just type `git checkout feature/ISSUE-123` and then hit tab to autocomplete the rest of the branch (even if the branch doesn't exist locally), but for some reason this doesn't work with `git switch`, if I type `git switch feaure/ISSUE-123` and hit tab nothing happens, even if the branch exists locally.

How do I get `git switch` to tab auto complete like `git checkout` does?

Details:

OS: Windows 10
Git version: 2.28.windows.1
Shell: PowerShell (running inside Windows Terminal)

I installed git by downloading and executing the Windows 10 64-bit installer available at https://git-scm.com

Comment: Your question is a little scarce on details: What operating system are you using, how did you install Git? What shell are you using?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry @DanielB, I forgot those details. I've edited the question to include them now

Comment: Git for Windows does not ship with PowerShell completion. Did you perhaps install Posh-Git?

Comment: Yes! I totally forgot, I thought I only had a pretty git prompt, but posh-git is also installed

Comment: I updated posh-git and it works now. Tab completion for these two commands are also in [their changelog](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/v1.0.0/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git for Windows does not ship with tab completion support for PowerShell. You had an outdated version of Posh-Git installed, a third-party package that provides tab completion for Git in PowerShell.

Much like the original completion support (developed with Git, for Bash, ZSH and tcsh), these need to be updated to support new/changed command line syntax, so make sure to update regularly.